# Shouldn't reputation be recalculated site-wide? StackExchange 1.0 question up-votes were worth 10 rep, not 5 rep.

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-migration

I just realized that my reputation didn't decrease when the site was migrated from the [basicallymoney.com](http://basicallymoney.com) Stack Exchange 1.0 site to this new Stack Exchange 2.0 site.

Given that SE 1.0 had question up-votes worth +10 reputation (i.e. the same as answer up-votes), whereas question up-votes on Stack Overflow and all other SE 2.0 sites are +5 reputation only, shouldn't reputation be recalculated here, site-wide, to ... hmm... how shall I say... **"restore balance to the force"**?  :-)

Comment: Teacher, you forgot to give us homework today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reputation will be recalculated across the site today.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a new user and it wouldn't bother me if rep was not recalculated.